# R plot where a value between two groups must equals to edge length and another value within for a group correspond to circle size

Tags: r, networking, plot

I am generating a plot where avg_Fst between populations must be corresponding to edge length in a network plot while avg_pi withing population must correspond to their circle size:
my data is this:

```
> dput(ab)
structure(list(pop1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
), class = "factor"), pop2 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E"), class = "factor"), avg_fst = c(0.231041917985128, 
0.254540018155449, 0.157917148615753, 0.169318976530272, 0.206532404009646, 
0.227900635079997, 0.206542382448551, 0.1579171, 0.25454, 0.2448414, 
0.2279006, 0.232717690663336, 0.217280266527118, 0.244841392841436
), avg_pi = c(0.146243900540299, 0.146243900540299, 0.157419015589505, 
0.15959110875081, 0.15959110875081, 0.15959110875081, 0.15959110875081, 
0.142, 0.142, 0.142, 0.142, 0.135976932610714, 0.135976932610714, 
0.135976932610714)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14"))
```

And with data I tried to generate a network plot using these codes:

```
# Create a graph from the avg_fst data
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(ab, directed = FALSE)

# Set vertex attributes (size based on avg_pi)
vertex_sizes <- setNames(ab$avg_pi, ab$pop1)
V(graph)$size <- vertex_sizes[V(graph)$name] * 1.5  # Increase circle size

# Set edge attributes (weight based on avg_fst)
E(graph)$weight <- ab$avg_fst

# Define colors for each population
population_colors <- c("A" = "blue", "B" = "green", "C" = "red", "D" = "purple", "E" = "orange")

# Plot the graph using ggraph with layout set to "nicely"
ggraph(graph, layout = "nicely") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(alpha = weight), color = "gray", size = 0.9) +  # Decrease line width
  geom_node_point(aes(size = size, color = name), alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), vjust = 1.5) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(20, 35)) +  # Adjust circle size range
  scale_color_manual(values = population_colors) +  # Assign colors manually
  labs(title = "Population Network",
       x = "X-Axis",
       y = "Y-Axis") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")  # Remove legend
```

And I want a plot something like this:
[image]

Using my codes I can't control the edge length in network plot and they look a bit different from the Fst values and they also don't look nice like in example plot.

How to produce a plot which I provide here in the example plot.

Thanks,